# Kibana: pie chart slices based on substring of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to create a pie chart visualization that will display the top 10 incoming requests.
I have a search query that filters only the incoming requests which have a field called messages which looks like the following:
"Incoming request /api/someaction".
How do I do the aggregation based on the /api/someaction part rather on the entire string (because then "Incoming" is counted as a term".

Or...can I create custom field which are, for example, a substring of another field?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Logstash or something else? If Logstash, how does your config look like?

Comment: I believe there is a way using the "advanced" JSON input. I am currently also looking into that but so far have not been able to find something.

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned earlier in the comment, I've come up with a solution to my problem. For me, I had values like `foo bar baz` and I needed to extract the first word. I was able to do this using the "Advanced → JSON" field, using the following script:

```
{
    "script": "( _value.indexOf(' ') > 0 ? _value.substring(0, _value.indexOf(' ')) : _value )"
}
```

So, in the Kibana interface this looks like this:

[image: Kibana visualisation config with scripted value]

---

So, in your case, the script should probably be something like:

```
{
    "script": "( _value.indexOf(' ') > 0 ? _value.substring(_value.lastIndexOf(' ')) : _value )"
}
```

Obviously, this assumes that the part of the message you want to extract follows the last space in the string. I've written a throwaway Java class to test the above:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String tester = "Incoming request /api/someaction";
        String result = tester.substring(tester.lastIndexOf(" "));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

As far as I can tell, you can use any Java code in the "script" key of the JSON field. So you should also be able to use regexes using [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or any other String method for that matter...

I haven't tested this though. If someone has any information on this, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Only issue is that if this pie is used in a dashboard, and a slice is clicked, it won't successfully filter the dashboard as it normally would.

Comment: @Tomty I've noticed that as well. And it does make sense in a way. Unfortunately I don't see a solution to that.